# How to change the default folder viewed when finder is opened

Tags: macos, finder

i just downloaded OS 10.9.2 after having 10.6.8 for the last few years. In 10.6.8, whenever I clicked on finder in the dock, I would get a finder window with the "user" folder opened immediately. in 10.9, this opens the "all my files" folder. Is there a way to change it back so that whenever I click on finder it, by default, opens to the user folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Finder → Preferences and change the default folder:

[image]